# When I ssh into my remote server, and use VIM to edit files, things are very strange

Tags: ssh, vim

For instance, when i press 'I' to go into insert mode, and then use the arrow keys to move around the line, the left arrow ends up inserting the letter 'D' one  line above the line I was intending to edit, the right arrow inserts a 'C' etc. Is this a server configuration thing, an SSH thing, a vim thing or what? Any advice is appreciated, I realize this is not exactly a programming question but I'm not sure where exactly else to file it.

Comment: You're using vim; why do you need arrow keys?

Comment: because there is no way that I know of to get to the end of the line in VIM without using the arrow keys. You press $ to get to the chartacter before the end of the line, but the way I usually get around this is to get the one character before the end of the line, go into Insert mode, then press right once

Comment: `$` moves to end of line, but `A` appends after end of line.  Each of `H`, `J`, `K`, and `L` move the cursor one line or character.  They are the `vi` arrow keys.

Comment: I like *also* having the arrow keys available for use in Vim. I use them in so many other applications on so many operating systems, reaching for them is hard-wired into my fingers.

Answer (score 4):

It's a terminal type problem.  The window creating the remote connection is not properly giving an understandable terminal type.  Or maybe the host doesn't recognize the terminal type and is punting to vt100 or something.

The specific ssh client and platform and the host type are needed for detailed help, but once you have connected and logged in, but before starting vim, type `echo $TERM`.  If it's blank or corrupted, try setting it to xterm and see if vim works better.

Comment: Both my local $TERM and the $TERM on the remote server are xterm-color. So should I change them to VT525? If so, how do I do so?
$TERM = VT525
?

Comment: Depends on what the client is.  `xterm-color` ought to be well-supported.  It could be that the client terminal isn't properly configured for your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This page says that manually setting the TERM variable is almost never a good idea, and suggests some alternatives:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Home_and_End_keys_not_working

Sure enough, for me, just *unsetting* my TERM variable fixed the problem, plus other problems like terminal colors too.

Answer (score 0):

Your local terminal and the remote side's `$TERM` settings don't match. Configure your client for VT110, VT220, or VT525 (the higher the better), then set `$TERM` on the remote side to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your home directory's `.profile` file:

```
TERM=xterm-color
```